# Internal data storage in MongoDB with WiredTiger

Tags: mongodb, internal, wiredtiger

I've read that MongoDB, with its new Storage Engine WiredTiger, now stores the data in BTrees and i wanna know what they meant by that. Is it any of the following?

I've seen a webinar where they talked about pages of the data files and they arranged them as a tree (with root page, internal page and leaf page), but they didn't say what the hierarchy was based on.
They also said that data files consist of key-value pairs. Is each key the _id and the value the entire document?
Someone told me that documents are no longer stored as BSON, but instead as a BTree, is that correct?

Thanks in advance.